# how to connect in mongodb realm to specific app/databse in android?

Tags: android, mongodb, kotlin, realm

I am trying to connect my android app to mongo-db realm.
I went over many tutorials but,
in all the tutorials there is the default set up of realm in my pp,
but I couldn't find how does mongo connect to my realm app.
I have a previous stitch app with an app id that I would like to connect to it.
But the only object that gets an app id , is the realm App object which is never used for data retrieval (in the tutorials).

so how does it work?
where do i pass my app id ? and to who?

thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can either

- Setup a *synced* Realm where changes are synchronized between your local Realm and Atlas with a *SyncConfiguration*, or
- Access the MongoDB Realm App directly through the remote API to *create/update/delete documents*, *call functions*, *watch for changes*, etc.

Both require you to initiale the `App` from your app id and authenticate a user.

All steps for *opening a synced Realm* can be found at https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/android/quick-start (with a full example at https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/android/quick-start#complete-example), while steps for *Instantiating a MongoDB Collection Handle* can be found at https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/android/mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the appId to the AppConfiguration Builder - see here:
https://github.com/mongodb-university/realm-tutorial-android-kotlin/blob/final/app/src/main/java/com/mongodb/tasktracker/TaskTracker.kt#L29

Comment: but then, in the example, where do you use the app? in all the examples that i saw the app is never used later. which means that the app is is passed somehow in the background?

Comment: the configuration is then passed to realm under the hood and you then can open synced realms from there - https://github.com/mongodb-university/realm-tutorial-android-kotlin/blob/final/app/src/main/java/com/mongodb/tasktracker/ProjectActivity.kt#L47